# uiCollectionViews in a uitableViewCells with swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, uicollectionview, xcode6

I have seen many examples of a uicollectionview in a tableview cell with older xcode versions, but am having trouble finding/figuring out how to develop using swift. I have been playing with this source code... http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-collection-view-using-swift/ , but am wondering how to introduce or build UICollectionViews in tableViewCells using Swift...?

Thank you in advance for any direction or resources on how to do this Using Swift and Storyboards?

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  UICollectionView
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}



//  CollectionViewCell.swift
//  UICollectionView
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    let textLabel: UILabel!
    let imageView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 16, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height*2/3))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        let textFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 32, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height/3)
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: textFrame)
        textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize())
        textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        contentView.addSubview(textLabel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are ;)

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

let data: Array<Int>= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell        
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Swift 2.0** example of collectionView inside a collectionViewCell, but the same applies to tableView's as well.

https://github.com/irfanlone/Collection-View-in-a-collection-view-cell

Using a collection view has certainly some advantages over tableviews in this case. Other useful Links:

Tutorial : https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Source Code: https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell

Hope that helps!!